# express server api returns empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am trying to get the data from mongodb using express server but all i am getting is empty array => []

However if i run the db.Goserv.find() in console i get the results right please help

here is the server.js file

```
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var schema = new Schema({

    type: String,
    address: String,

    servicecost: String

}, { collection: 'Goserv' });





var Goserv = mongoose.model('Goserv', schema  );

 module.exports = Goserv ;


    app.get('/api/centre', function(req, res) {


        Goserv.find(function(err, centre){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
           } else {
                res.json(centre);
                console.log(centre);
           }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var schema = new Schema({

    type: String,
    address: String,

    servicecost: String

}, { collection: 'Goserv' });





var Goserv = mongoose.model('Goserv', schema  );

 module.exports = Goserv ;


    app.get('/api/centre', function(req, res) {


        Goserv.find({},function(err, centre){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
           } else {
                res.json(centre);
                console.log(centre);
           }

        });

    });
```

Comment: ok ,! now i notice the curly braces , but i had already tried with that too. Still [ ] empty

Comment: You have missed `query` parameter.

Comment: If this collection has data it must be return

Comment: Okay ! But its still not working ! Anything wrong with the code?